# drank wine or whiskey

Tags: meaning, conjunctions, ambiguity

a. The guests drank wine or whiskey.

b. The guests drank either wine or whiskey.

Are the above sentences ambiguous?

I think they could be used in these two cases:

1. They all drank one of the two
2. Some drank one, the others other

But I think they could even be used if there were some guests who didn't drink anything at all.

Is that correct?

Comment: The ambiguity as regards whether ***all*** the guests had ***the same*** drink is present regardless of whether you include optional ***either*** or not. So far as I'm concerned, the only real difference of emphasis is that because including ***either*** more strongly emphasises the fact of there being a "binary choice", if you ***do*** include it, this carries a slightly stronger implication that ***every guest drank one or the other*** (there were no "teetotal" abstentions).

Comment: Note that the phrasing of your first possible meaning is ***still*** ambiguous. Contextually, it's obvious you want it to mean *They all drank **the same** one of the two*, but in principle it could be used to mean ***every** guest drank one of the two possibilities* (some chose whisky, some wine; there were no abstentions).

Comment: In Scotland and Canada they make and drink whisky, spelled like that with no 'e'.

Comment: I'd interpret this as 1) because for 2) it would be much more natural to use *and*.